# Multiple web app static outbound IPs with one NAT Gateway(Azure)

Tags: .net, azure, ip, devops, azure-webapps

I currently have 2 web app services in Azure(let's say 1 webappA and 1 webapp2). I need 1 static outbound IP address for each web app, so 2 IPs in total.
I found a solution by using a NAT gateway. It looks straightforward to get a static outbound IP for 1 web app. But a bit more complicated for when I try with two web apps.

I want a cost efficient solution, so I don't want to have 2 NAT Gateways( 1 NAT for each web app).

Does anyone one knows how I can force Azure NAT Gateway to associate one IP for webapp1 and one IP for webapp2?
Because it looks like NAT Gateway picks randomly the IPs from the list(outbound IPs tab in NAT Gateway)

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

1. Created a virtual network with one subnet. [image]
2. Created NAT gateway with one public IP attached to a subnet in VNet [image]
3. Created Outbound IP with Public IP
   [image]
4. Created two app services and enabled VNET integration which has NAT gateway configured with public IP. [image] [image]

**Note:**
I’m able to achieve this with one Public IP, if separate IP required for each app then we have to create two NAT gateways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, with 1 app is ok. I was wandering if there is a way to "route" in the nat gateway traffic to 1 app or other depending on ip

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have been facing similar issue and I found out a solution from this link [this link explains how we can use one NAT gateway with multiple VNETS using hub and spoke topology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nat-gateway/tutorial-hub-spoke-route-nat)

Here We have more than two vnets and each vnet has route table which is pointing traffic to a VM which is acting as a Network Virtual Appliance.
This Network Virtual Appliance can be Azure Firewall but it costs around 1000$ so a VM can be used if cost is a deciding factor.